# Aerospike UDF module not found

Tags: aerospike

I'm writing a stream UDF for Aerospike 3.6.2, and I'd like to put some code in a separate Lua module.  I followed the [example](https://www.aerospike.com/docs/udf/developing_lua_modules.html) exactly and created a file `mymodule.lua` with the following contents:

```
local exports = {}

function exports.one()
  return 1
end

function exports.two()
  return 2
end

return exports
```

and put my UDF in a file `testUdf.lua`:

```
local MM = require('mymodule')

local function three()
    return MM.one() + MM.two()
end

function testUdf(stream)
    local type = three()
    local testFilter = function(record)
        return record.campaignType == type
    end
    return stream : filter(testFilter)
end
```

I register both modules and execute a query from the Java client:

```
LuaConfig.SourceDirectory = this.udfPath;

List<RegisterTask> tasks = new ArrayList<>();
for (String udfName : new String[] { "mymodule.lua", "testUdf.lua" }) {
    File udf = new File (this.udfPath, udfName);
    tasks.add (this.aerospike.register (null, udf.getPath(), udfName, Language.LUA));
}
tasks.stream().forEach (RegisterTask::waitTillComplete);

Statement stmt = new Statement();
stmt.setNamespace (getRawFactNamespace());
stmt.setSetName (SET_FACT);
stmt.setFilters (Filter.equal (BIN_PRODUCT_CODE, "UX"));
stmt.setBinNames (FACT_BINS);

int count = 0;
try (ResultSet rs = this.aerospike.queryAggregate (null, stmt, "testUdf", "testUdf")) {
    while (rs.next()) {
        count++;
    }
}
```

I see the lua files, with the correct contents, on both of my test Aerospike servers in `aerospike/var/udf/lua`, which is where `mod-lua.user-path` points to in `aerospike.conf`.  I logged package.path and it includes the `aerospike/var/udf/lua` directory as well.

But when I invoke my UDF, I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.aerospike.client.AerospikeException: org.luaj.vm2.LuaError: testUdf:1 module 'mymodule' not found: mymodule
  no field package.preload['mymodule']
  mymodule.lua
  no class 'mymodule'
stack traceback:
  testUdf:1: in main chunk
  [Java]: in ?
  at com.aerospike.client.query.QueryExecutor.checkForException(QueryExecutor.java:122)
  at com.aerospike.client.query.ResultSet.next(ResultSet.java:78)
  ...
Caused by: org.luaj.vm2.LuaError: testUdf:1 module 'mymodule' not found: mymodule
  no field package.preload['mymodule']
  mymodule.lua
  no class 'mymodule'
stack traceback:
  testUdf:1: in main chunk
  [Java]: in ?
  at org.luaj.vm2.LuaValue.error(Unknown Source)
  at org.luaj.vm2.lib.PackageLib$require.call(Unknown Source)
  at org.luaj.vm2.LuaClosure.execute(Unknown Source)
  at org.luaj.vm2.LuaClosure.onInvoke(Unknown Source)
  at org.luaj.vm2.LuaClosure.invoke(Unknown Source)
  at org.luaj.vm2.LuaValue.invoke(Unknown Source)
  at com.aerospike.client.lua.LuaInstance.loadPackage(LuaInstance.java:113)
  at com.aerospike.client.query.QueryAggregateExecutor.runThreads(QueryAggregateExecutor.java:92)
  at com.aerospike.client.query.QueryAggregateExecutor.run(QueryAggregateExecutor.java:77)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you add all relevant code (java and lua) ? The example works very well when registered via ascii-program

Comment: I tried your code with no problems. Perhaps retry your code with the default path aerospike/usr/udf/lua (i.e no specification under mod-lua)? After a cluster restart, of course.